# How to use cloud armor to block a POST request that contains a certain text in the POST body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I recently received a lot of traffic from bots. However they were using the same device on which my code was able to fingerprint and this info is sent in the POST request body like

`{ 'deviceid':'ABC123' }`

I am using Google Cloud and Cloud Armor and was wondering how I can configure Cloud Armor rules to block requests that have the `ABC123`  inside of the POST body?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm my comment. You can't read the message content, you can only get and check the [request metadata attributes (header included)](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of supported attributes for creating any custom rules https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#attributes

And this doesn't let you create custom rules based on http post body content.